# Captar valor de input (Somente os campos numéricos) e colocar em Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar uma função que pegue o valor de um campo input e coloque em div. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Obs: Preciso pegar somente os valores numéricos.

### Segue o meu código:

```js
$( "#testar" ).click(function() {

    $('#txtDistancia').on('input', function () {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $('#valorkm').html(valor);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="distancia" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="7,5 km">
<p></p>
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="testar" class="btn btn-success" />
<p></p>
<div id="valorkm"></div>
```

UPDATE: Eu gostaria que a pessoa testasse o código localhost, pois duas pessoas me ajudaram, eu vi o código funcionando aqui e também por meio do Fiddle, mas ao testar em localhost não funciona.

Comment: Aparece algum erro na consola do browser? esse javascript está definido no html depois do include do jquery certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está testando pelo botão não precisa do `on input`. E para capturar somente os números pode usar:

`match(/\d+/g)`

**Exemplo**

```js
$("#testar").click(function() {

  let valor = $('#txtDistancia').val().match(/\d+/g);
  $('#valorkm').html(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="distancia" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="7,5 km">
<p></p>
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="testar" class="btn btn-success" />
<p></p>
<div id="valorkm"></div>
```

Comment: eu tentei colocar sua solução no meu código, mas não funciona. [Veja aqui](http://galeria.net.br/teste/).

Comment: monte seu código num Fiddle @Wendell, pf

Comment: No Fiddle funciona, mas tanto localhost quanto no servidor não funciona. O que pode ser? [Veja o código no Fiddle aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/vs2b6mte/).

Comment: @Wendell Na página que vc informou, a ordem das coisas estão erradas: a primeira coisa que vc deve carregar é a biblioteca jQuery, depois o HTML e por fim script. Vc alterou a ordem das coisas, por isso não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```js
$( "#testar" ).click(function() {
  var valor = $('#txtDistancia').val().replace(/[^0-9^,]/g, '');
  $('#valorkm').html(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="distancia" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="7,5 km">
<p></p>
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="testar" class="btn btn-success" />
<p></p>
<div id="valorkm"></div>
```

Comment: eu tentei colocar sua solução no meu código, mas não funcionou. [Veja aqui](http://galeria.net.br/teste2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Solução com javascript puro** um regex para eliminar todos os caracteres nao-numeros

```js
function Testar(){
  var distancia = document.getElementById('txtDistancia').value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
  document.getElementById('valorkm').innerText=distancia;
};
```

```html
<input name="distancia" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="7,5 km">
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="testar" class="btn btn-success" onclick='Testar();' />
<div id="valorkm"></div>
```

**Caso deva retornar um numero com separador . (ponto)**

Use o parseFloat para converter para Number, assim basta trocar a `,` por `.` para o parseFloat conseguir trabalhar com o numero

```js
function Testar(){
  var distancia = document.getElementById('txtDistancia').value;
  var numero = parseFloat(distancia.replace(',', '.'));
  document.getElementById('valorkm').innerText=numero;
};
```

```html
<input name="distancia" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="7,5 km">
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="testar" class="btn btn-success" onclick='Testar();' />
<div id="valorkm"></div>
```

> O argumento de parseFloat deve ser uma string ou uma expressão de string. O resultado parseFloat é o número cuja representação decimal estava contida nessa string (ou **o número encontrado no início da string** que é o caso em questão quando trocamos a `,` por `.` ).